# Different notions of a stabilizer of a group action in characteristic $p$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

From a paper I'm reading, $G^x$ denotes the stabilizer of a point $x \in X(E')$ in a variety $X$ under the action of an algebraic group $G$.

[image]

I had a question about what was said at the end.  In characteristic $p$, what else can be meant by the stabilizer of $x$ except the usual thing?  It is the $E'$ subgroup scheme $G^x$ of $G_{E'}$ defined on points by

$$G^x(E'') = \{ g \in G(E'') : g.x = x \}$$

for all fields $E''$ containing $E'$.

Comment: The stabilizer of a point $p$ in $X(k)$ is the fiber over the point $(p,p)\in (X\times_{\text{Spec}\ k}X)(k)$ with respect to the morphism $$\Psi:G\times_{\text{Spec}\ k} X \to X\times_{\text{Spec}\ k}X,\ \ (g,x)\mapsto (g\cdot x,x).$$  In positive characteristic, this fiber might be a nonreduced, closed subgroup scheme of $G$.  Over a characteristic $0$ field $F$, every group scheme is smooth (hence reduced) by Cartier's theorem.

Comment: Thus it is not enough to consider only fields containing $E'$. One must consider all commutative rings containing $E'$.